# Is replacing the call to mutual exclusive methods by an injected strategy overengineering?

Tags: clean-code, solid, single-responsibility, open-closed-principle

I recently gave advice to refactor some code along the lines of

```
class Validator<T> : IValidator
{
    public ValidationResult Validate(Validatable thingToValidate)
    {
        if(typeof(T).Name == nameof(FooThing))
        {
            ValidateFoo(thingToValidate);
        }
        if(typeof(T).Name == nameof(BarThing))
        {
            ValidateBar(thingToValidate);
        }
        if(typeof(T).Name == nameof(QuxThing))
        {
            ValidateQux(thingToValidate);
        }
    }
}
```

to something like

```
class Validator<T> : IValidator
{
    Dictionary<string, IValidator> specificValidators; // may be injected

    public ValidationResult Validate(Validatable thingToValidate)
    {
        var specificValidator = GetValidatorFor(typeof(T).Name);
        return specificValidator.Validate(thingToValidate);
    }

    private IValidator GetValidatorFor(string name)
    {
        return specificValidators[name];
    }
}
```

While I tend to argue that this use of generics is misuse, I intentionally tried to keep the public interface intact.

The rationale to refactor the original code was, that it was quite rigid and had too many responsibilities (at the end of the day, the class was responsible to validate Foo-things, Bar-things and Qux-things). More specifically I argued that

- The OCP was hurt, since it's not able to extend the class without changing it
- The SRP was hurt for the reasons stated above

While I think that these arguments hold in order to keep the class maintainable (if it was just one more validation case added, the change would not have a large impact, but if it were ten more cases, the class would really get unwieldy, furthermore, adding the cases manually is error-prone), but surely the latter version is way less readable.

Admittedly I am not quite sure if this is overengeneering, or if this refactoring is sound and required to maintain a high maintainability. Is it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is more important? SOLID or KISS?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/367092/what-is-more-important-solid-or-kiss)

Comment: @DocBrown Definitely the questions *are* related. Anyway, I think that my case is a bit more specific, especially regarding extensibility and maintainability, giving a rationale *why* I think that the proposed principles are important in that case and asking if that is sound.

Comment: A switch like that means you can use a factory pattern to create your validator which it looks like you did. I do find it weird that your 'super validator' and the specific validators both implement the same interface.

Comment: @Carra You are correct that a factory would be better.

Comment: @DavidArno: the first code snippet in this question is more following "KISS", the second more "SOLID". That makes my answer to that other question a good match here as well . And don't forget, voting as "dupe" is a way to link closely related questions together, this is no critics.

Comment: Use the simplest possible design and avoid cargo cult designs. The simplest code is produced by the best developers.

Answer (score 3):

Your Validator is both a factory that creates a Validator and a Validator. This still does too much.

What I normally do is create a specific Validator per object and inject the correct one.

Example:

```
public UserController
{
  private IValidator<User> _userValidator;
  public UserController(IValidator<User> validator)
  {
    _userValidator = validator;
  }
}

public Validator<User> : IValidator<User>
{
  public ValidationResult Validate(User user)
  { 
  }
}
```

You can then pass the correct validator through a factory or through an Injection Framework by registering the correct IValidator< User >.

Adding a new Validator is then creating a new one and registering it in the factory or Injection Framework.

Comment: Are your validators and objects always in a one-to-one correspondence?  If they are, then why bother with all those objects and validation injection?  Why not just let the objects validate themselves, say, by checking them in the constructor?

Comment: User could be a POCO object. in that case, checking the object is better done in a validator.

Comment: Presumably your POCOs are coming from a database, where the data is already valid.  The term POCO already suggests that it doesn't have validation; one way to remedy that is to make it no longer a POCO.

Comment: There's no use validating data coming from the db. But before calling an add or update I validate my users. For example: is the age reasonable?

Answer (score 0):

I almost agree with Carra. Your approach is doctored and does not give you all you want, Carra's kills the Validator-Validatable tandem.

I would rather see something like this:

```
abstract class Validator : IValidator
{
    public ValidationResult Validate(Validatable thingToValidate)
    {
        return DoValidate(thingToValidate);
    }

    protected abstract ValidationResult DoValidate(Validatable thingToValidate);

    protected void CheckType(Validatable thingToValidate, Type type)
    {
        if (typeof(thingToValidate) != type)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Wrong type.");
        }

    }
}

class FooValidator : Validator
{
    protected override ValidationResult DoValidate(Validatable thingToValidate)
    {
        CheckType(thingToValidate, typeof(Foo));

        // if this were not a direct descendant of Validator, you would call
        // base.DoValidate(thingToValidate);

        // Foo specific validation
    }
}
```

One validator class for each validatable type that descends from an abstract class Validator. This way

- you respect the existing interface;
- you get SRP;
- you get OCP;
- there is no abusive use of generics.